# Azure Firewall not creating entries in Log Workspace

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to collect the outbound logs for an Azure FW. So I have the diagnostics settings enabled for

-AzureFirewallApplicationRule

-AzureFirewallNetworkRule

-AzureFirewallDnsProxy

Also the Destination Table is set to be Resource-specific. But I dont see anything getting sent to the destination log workspace after waiting a whole day.

Any ideas?

Comment: Resource specific table is a part of the structured firewall log and that feature is still in preview. "By default, the new resource specific tables are disabled. Open a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) to enable the functionality in your environment." Reference: [Structured firewall logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-preview#structured-firewall-logs-preview)

Comment: Thanks! yes, I got it working by not using resource-type specific logging.